# Filtering search results in the views by associated records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, filtering, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to implement basic records filtration in my Rails application. But I have problem with filtering by `belongs_to` and `has_many` associations.

I have 3 models: `Job`, `JobCategory`, `Tag`. Tags are implemented via `acts_as_taggable_on` gem.
There are some scopes in my `Job` model, that looks like work correctly:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job_category
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags

  scope :join_tags, -> { includes(:tags) }
  scope :salary_min, lambda { |salary_min|
    where('salary_min >= ? or salary_min IS NULL', salary_min)
      .where('salary_max >= ? or salary_max IS NULL', salary_min)
      .where('salary_min >= ? or salary_min IS NULL', salary_min)
  }
  scope :salary_max, lambda { |salary_max|
    where('salary_min <= ? or salary_min IS NULL', salary_max)
      .where('salary_max <= ? or salary_max IS NULL', salary_max)
  }
  scope :by_category, lambda { |*category_id|
    includes(:job_categories).where(job_category_id: category_id)
  }
  scope :tagged_with_id, lambda { |*tag_id|
    joins(:taggings).where(taggings: { tag_id: tag_id })
  }
end
```

My index action in `JobsController` is:

```
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @jobs = Job.tagged_with(params[:tag])
                 .filter(params.slice(:salary_min, :salary_max, :by_category, :tagged_with_id))
    else
      @jobs = Job.published.filter(params.slice(:salary_min, :salary_max, :by_category, :tagged_with_id))
                 .join_tags
    end
    @job_categories = JobCategory.all
  end
```

I can call 2 scopes from view:

```
= form_for jobs_path, method: 'get' do |f|
  = f.label 'Salary from'
  = text_field_tag :salary_min, params[:salary_min]

  = f.label 'Salary to'
  = text_field_tag :salary_max, params[:salary_max]

  = f.submit 'Filter', name: nil
```

How can I call other scopes to filter records by multiple categories and tags?
I need to call `by_category` and `tagged_with_id` scopes, but don't understand how can I do it correctly.

In other forms in my app I use next 2 form helpers:

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :job_category_ids, JobCategory.order('priority DESC'), :id, :title, hide_label: true
= f.collection_select :tag_list, ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.order(:name), :name, :name, {hide_label: true}, html_options = {class: 'js-example-basic-multiple', multiple: 'multiple'}
```

I would like to use these helpers, but with passing filters parameters to the controller, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

first get your `category_ids` in an array

```
category_ids = JobCategory.order('priority DESC').pluck(:id)
```

then [passing in arguments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) to your scope in the format of an array. This are [`subset conditions`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions)

```
scope :by_category, ->(category_ids) {    
     where(job_category_id: category_ids)
  }
```

I checked [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5384436/verrom) and given your previous experience on ruby on rails, I believe you will not have problems figuring the rest of the code

thanks!